# undefined method `page' for #<ActiveRecord::Relation:0x000001054d1a38>

Tags: ruby-on-rails-3

trying to add pagination to my app (pages numbers at the bottom of the page)
getting error "undefined method `page' for #"

added 2 gems  `'will_paginate', '3.0.3'
gem 'bootstrap-will_paginate', '0.0.6'`
ran `bundle install` & `rails s`

added the line to my app/controllers/pins_controller.rb

```
def index
  @pins = Pin.order("created_at desc").page(params[:page]).per_page(20)
end
```

Added pagination to the pins index view - app/views/pins/index.html.erb

```
<%= render 'pages/home' %>

<div id="pins">
  <%= render @pins %>
</div>

<%= will_paginate @pins %>
```

but get this error message

NoMethodError in PinsController#index
undefined method `page' for #

app/controllers/pins_controller.rb:6:in `index'

Comment: update... the web app now loads correctly wothout the error message but still does not show the page numbers at the bottom of the page?

Comment: @pins = Pin.order("created_at desc").page(params[:page]).per_page(20)   added 20+ pins (photos) shows the 20 oins but no page numbers

Answer (score 0):

fixed !  Change <% will_paginate @pins %> to <%= will_paginate @pins %>